# Making a vector more efficient while adding elements

Tags: c++, vector, processing-efficiency

I am thinking of making the vector data structure more efficient.

Suppose it is for some generic data type T...then while adding a new element to the vector, what the current std::vector does is to reallocate a whole new memory chunk of n+1 elements.

What I want to do...

I wrote a small program :

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{

    int *i,*j;
    i=new int;
    cout<<i;
    delete i;
    j=new int ;
    cout<<j;
    delete j;

        return 0;
}
```

Both Memory Locations were The Same...

Now What i am thinking is that first i will allocate memory for the generic data type like this :

```
T *temp=new T;
```

Now Compare the memory address of temp to the address of last element of the vector....If they differ by `sizeof (T)` then i will add the new element there itself....else do it the way `std::vector` does it....

So It reduces the cost of copying all the elements...if the data is large then this can make a significant difference......!!

Pls tell me if i am on the right track...

Comment: Vectors cannot do what you describe because that would cause `push_back` to not fulfill its amortized constant time complexity. Vectors are pretty darn efficient, especially with C++11, where the  elements can be moved instead of copied when a reallocation occurs. Also, your memory address tricks are not in any way guaranteed, so no, that won't work portably at all.

Comment: [`std::vector::reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve)

Comment: No...i have tried this with my own implementation of vector...the deletion operation will be of constant time complexity...what i am doing is, only if there is enough space adjacent to the last element of the vector, i am telling not to copy all the stuff to a diff. location, but to allocate it adjacent to the last element itself....

Comment: Sorry, I meant your claim of *while adding a new element to the vector, what the current std::vector does is to reallocate a whole new memory chunk of n+1 elements.* This makes `push_back` O(N).

Comment: i don't to reserve unnecessary memory...i want to make it both memory and time efficient

Comment: @PRP, `std::vector` is already memory and time efficient. Of course depending on the specific needs, another container might work better, but there's a reason the general advice is to use `std::vector`.

Comment: yea my implementation will make insertion into a vector CONSTANT TIME....isn't that great....??

Comment: the current one is O(n)...mine will be constant time O(1) when enough memory will be there adjacent to the last element...i find that very time efficient...

Comment: @PRP, And then it will break as soon as you, say, upgrade your compiler. But the thing is it's already practically constant time. It is not O(N), it's amortized constant. If you do it a million times, the number of times it's O(N) is negligible.

Comment: @PRP The current one is *amortised constant time.* `std::vector` doesn't allocate `n + 1`, it allocates `2 * n` (or some other multiple), so that the reallocations happen less frequently and over a large number of insertions, it evens out so that the time for one insertion is constant. That's what *amortised time complexity* means.

Comment: but then if it allocates/reserves 2*n time the elements then its not memory efficient right....my implementation will allocate exactly the required memory of n elements....

Comment: @PRP, Your implementation also does a memory allocation on every single insertion. That hurts time a ton (not complexity, but you'll notice a huge difference). With moves being constant time, that would be equivalent to `std::vector` only allocating one extra element per insertion.

Comment: doesn't this question show ORIGINAL Research effort...??? Why is it being voted down if not up.....??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand your idea as

> If `new` gives me back an address which is contiguous with the memory already held by the `MyVector` object, I will just use it without reallocating.

Yes, this could indeed work in theory. However, in practice, it's impossible to obtain such a contiguous address, because the allocator will most likely store some internal data at the start of the block it allocates (such as its size, or a pointer to the next block, or whatever).

Exact details depend on the allocator used by your standard library (and eventuall OS), but here's an example of typical behaviour. You call `new T` where `sizeof(T)` is 16 (for example). `operator new` calls `malloc` internally, which calls your OS's allocation function. That function allocates 20 bytes of memory at address `X`. It stores "16" in the first 4 bytes at `X`, and returns the address `X + 4` to `malloc`, which in turn returns it to `operator new` and that to your application. So there's no way you'll ever get contiguous memory.

Comment: yeahhh....i had read about malloc's working...you are correct...!! Dint cross my mind while thinking such a crazy idea....answer will be accepted...

Comment: One More Idea Crossed My mind....i did some experiments with the way malloc allocates the memory...the code above i have written will check whether memory is available or not....now if memory is available then...what i will do is to go to the memory where malloc stores its "meta-data" and and modify it so that it thinks that it had allocated more memory than it actually did.....and so the efficient vector can be implemented....

Comment: @PRP And what if that "more memory" you fictively claim is already taken by something? Plus, your code will be tightly coupled to the particular implementation of `malloc` on which you do this. And anyway, complexity in small cases doesn't matter. And complexity of large cases in `std::vector` is already amortised constant. Is that so bad for your case?

Comment: nope...i have implemented my own vector data structure in C++ and was thinking of ways to optimize it...thats all